# What is the best way to move Android Development Tools to another computer?

Tags: android, eclipse, dependencies, adt, move

i'm using Android Development Tools (Eclipse 3.8 Juno) in Linux Mint (version 17 Qiana) and i have to move to another computer (with Linux Mint Cinnamon Edition).
The project i'm developing in ADT includes google-play-services library and a couple of other libraries. In addition it has plugins for git and svn.
I copied the entire folder `adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702` to my new computer and i also copied `.android` and `.eclipse` folder to my new home.
At the first startup of ADT on new computer i get error on all 4 folder inside my workspace. I tried to make Clean first on `android-support-v7-appcompat` and then on `google-play-services_lib` and the errors on those 2 folders disappeared but the errors on the other two folders (a library and my project) became exclamation marks.
If i do right click on the library and go to `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Libraries` tab i see error on `Android Dependencies`, it says:

```
google-play-services_lib.jar - /my_workspace/google-play-services_lib/bin (missing)
```

If i do right click on my project and i see 3 errors:

```
android-support-v7-appcompat.jar - /my_workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/bin (missing)
library.jar - /my_workspace/library/bin (missing)
google-play-services_lib.jar - /my_workspace/google-play-services_lib/bin (missing)
```

Why i get this errors and how to solve them?
Otherwise... what is the best way to move ADT to another computer?

Comment: Why not a fresh install on your new machine then importing the project through source control ?

Comment: Then how to keep the right API version, the android .keystore file, and other things? Is it possible?

Comment: There is no fresh install, now Android Studio is the official IDE, so i should install Eclipse and then the ADT plugin...

Comment: You could (should ?) convert your project to AS and Gradle anyway, and update the tools at the same time. You can keep the keystore file.

Comment: I'm afraid it will not work... it is for this that i'm trying to stay on Eclipse